# Why is Quartz Scheduler not checking existence of JobDetail properly?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have the following method that builds a new `JobDetail` instance;

```
    private JobDetail getJob(JobID jobID) throws SchedulerException {
        Class<? extends Job> jobClass = jobID.getJobClass();
        if(jobClass != null){
            return JobBuilder
                    .newJob(jobClass)
                    .withIdentity(jobID.jobName(), jobID.jobGroup())
                    .requestRecovery(true)
                    .build();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Note: `JobID` is just a helper class of mine that provides all the necessary raw data required to build a `JobDetail`

Then another method that does the actual scheduling;

```
    doSchedule(Scheduler scheduler, JobDetail job, String triggerName){

        Trigger trigger = buildSomeTrigger(triggerName);

        //check whether job exists in scheduler instance
        if(scheduler.checkExists(job.getKey())){

            //If trigger also exists, then it probably holds new info
            //So, reschedule the existing job with the trigger
            if(scheduler.checkExists(trigger.getKey())){
                System.out.println("update job with Trigger");

                job = job.getJobBuilder().storeDurably(true).build();
                scheduler.addJob(job, true);
                Trigger oldTrigger = scheduler.getTrigger(trigger.getKey());
                scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), trigger);
            }else{

                //If trigger does not exist, it's an entirely new trigger
                //Add the new trigger to the existing job
                System.out.println("save new trigger for job");

                trigger = trigger.getTriggerBuilder().forJob(job).build();
                scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger);
            }
        }else{

            //If job does not exist, schedule new job with the trigger
            System.out.println("schedule new job with trigger");

            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** Here's what **`getNewSchedulerInstance()`** looks like;

```
    private Scheduler getNewSchedulerInstance() {
        Scheduler scheduler = null;
        try {
            scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory("quartz.properties").getScheduler();
            scheduler.setJobFactory(cdiJobFactory); //<== Utilizes the JobFactory implementation specified in the CdiJobFactory.java class
            scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(new SimpleJobListener());
            scheduler.getListenerManager().addTriggerListener(new SimpleTriggerListener());
        } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
            System.out.println("Scheduler instantiation failed!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return scheduler;
    }
```

Then finally in another method, I have the following;

```
    //This returns a new instance of Scheduler
    Scheduler scheduler = getNewSchedulerInstance();

    if(scheduler != null){
        JobID jobID = new ExtendedJobID(); // <== extends JobID

        JobDetail job = getJob(jobID);
        doSchedule(scheduler, job);
    }
```

***Normally I expect this to print;***

> schedule new job with trigger

***But instead it's printing;***

> save new trigger for job

**EDIT:** And hence throws the following exception;

```
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger 'GOALS.ACTIVATE_GOALS_0:0' for 'GOALS.ACTIVATE_GOALS' job:
The job (GOALS.ACTIVATE_GOALS) referenced by the trigger does not exist. 
[See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: The job (GOALS.ACTIVATE_GOALS) referenced by the trigger does not exist.]
```

- This suggests that the `scheduler.checkExists(job.getKey())` returns `true`
- `scheduler.checkExists(trigger.getKey())` returns `false`
- Yet exception says that `The job (*jobName*) referenced by the (*trigger*) does not exist`

So, this issuse only gets me confused as it seems that `scheduler.checkExists(...)` is failing to appropriately check the existence of the job or not in the scheduler

The Exception shouldn't even get thrown if the check did what I expect it to do;

But as you can see, the `JobDetail` is newly built and has not in any way been previously associated with the scheduler...

- So I'm wondering whether i'm missing some Quartz Scheduler points?...
- If so, can someone please explain what I might be doing wrong here?...
- Or could this actually be a bug?...
- Are there any work-arounds?

Comment: Are you sure you're not adding another job with the same key to the scheduler? It might help to post more of the calling code in order to help more.  

Could you post what getNewSchedulerInstance() does?  You could be returning the same Scheduler by accident?  Just ideas since we dont have the full source.

Comment: @Kurtymckurt... I added more information to the original Question

Comment: So now, if the scheduler finds that it exists, you're adding it again.

Comment: Actually it's rescheduling the job with the trigger, cos the trigger is either a new one or its metrics might have changed if it previously existed

Comment: There's still some place that you're adding the job with the same job key twice. I don't believe there's a bug with the Quartz Scheduler.

Comment: @Kurtymckurt..  So I added the entire code (I was going to avoid going through that stress by just posting the SCSC)... Anyways I also added some comments too to butress what's exactly going on.... The `doSchedule(...)` method is the only place that any scheduling gets done across the entire code-base